# git ls-files --modified lists deleted files as well

Tags: git

```
git ls-files --modified
```

is supposed to list only modified files. However, it includes deleted files as well.

On the other hand,

```
git ls-files --deleted
```

lists only the deleted files, which is expected.

Why are deleted files considered by git as modified when there is a separate command just to list deleted files?

System info:

```
> git --version
git version 1.7.1

> lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-ia32:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.8 (Final)
Release:        6.8
Codename:       Final

> uname -m
x86_64

> echo $0
/bin/tcsh
```

Comment: Strange: I don't see modified option in https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/commands/command_ls_files.go. Only --deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just FYI for those looking for an alternative command to list modified files, excluding deleted files, without the need to parse/interpret the output for further processing -

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M
```

Comment: you can use `--diff-filter=MA` for modified or added files, default filter is `MAD`

Answer (score 1):

`git ls-files --modified` considers a deleted file modified, because it is in fact modified (so much so as to be entirely missing).

If you need to subtract off deleted files from the `--modified` or `-m` output, you have various options:

- use `git status --porcelain` (not sure if this exists in the truly ancient Git you're using with CentOS here), and interpret its output;
- use `git ls-files` twice, once to get the modified-including-deleted list, then again to get the deleted list, and subtract off the deleted files; or
- use `git ls-files -m -d -t` (which can be compressed to `git ls-files -mdt`) and interpret its output.

For my test case for this last one, I took a clone of the Git repository for Git, modified the Makefile slightly in the working tree, and removed `zlib.c` from the working tree:

```
$ git ls-files -mdt
C Makefile
R zlib.c
C zlib.c
```

Note how `zlib.c` appears twice, once as `R`emoved, and once as `C`hanged (modified).  It is just a small matter of programming to have the `R` status override the `C` status when you read the results.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did suspect the same but wanted to confirm. Check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68330396/4726668 for a method to do this without the need to parse/interpret the output for further processing.

Comment: Yes, `git diff` will do the trick (in fact that's probably better than `git status --porcelain`, which runs *two* diffs, though the extra one is extra-low-cost here). However `git ls-files` has those special features with excludes. I do think there should be a way to have `git ls-files` not print deleted files as "modified", just from a general usefulness point of view.

Comment: +1
Oh ok, sounds good. Since you also recommend git diff, I've marked my answer as the answer for this question, but I learnt something new from yours, so upvoted. Thanks!